# run python script multiple times at the same time in 1x exe with different inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, csv, task

i want to run my py code multiple times, with different inputs & all at the same time with one exe.

My informations are all saved in one csv, & my problem is i dont know how i can run my script multiple times at the same time, with different inputs.
My code is still the same but i need some other inputs in it from the csv.

So as example:
my csv has 20 rows so my code will run 20 times, but in every row is another argument what i need.

if anyone know how this works, would be glad.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

do you means: there's a 20 rows in a csv file, and you wanna choose one of the  line in the file randomly?

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("your_csv.csv")

import random
x = random.randint(0, 20)
print(data[:, x])
```

if you want to run the file 20 times, and handle a line each time, you need to save the current run step in some file:

```
step = 0
with open('step.txt', mode='r+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    line = f.read()
    if line is not None:
        step = int(line)
    if step >= 20 or step < 0:
        step = 0

    data = data[:, step]
    # your logic to handle current line
    step = step + 1
    f.write(str(step))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but i want to run my code like this:
when my csv has 10,20 or 50 lines i want to run it at the same time multiple times as many as the csv is long you understand?